# Ngnix Rewrite rules - include path on url

Tags: nginx

I have an application with 2 domains.

One of them www.dominiolisboa.com I need to redirect the requests of the `/` to `/lisboa/pt-PT`

When someone type www.dominiolisboa.com needs to be redirected to www.dominiolisboa.com/lisboa/pt-PT

I've tried the following rule

```
server {
        listen 80;
  server_name  rockinriolisboa.sapo.pt www.rockinriolisboa.sapo.pt;
        location / {
           rewrite ^ /lisboa/pt-BR/$request_uri permanent;
        }
}
```

But this way I get the error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set `location = /` instead of `location /`.

`/` matches every request. `=` matches the exact url, therefore only the root location will be redirected.

Your config should remain like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  rockinriolisboa.sapo.pt www.rockinriolisboa.sapo.pt;
    location = / {
        rewrite ^ /lisboa/pt-BR permanent;
    }
}
```

For further information on how a request is processed by nginx, check [this    page](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) from the official site.